# How to flat and merge values in a dictionary using python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'Date' : ['2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01'],
     'Country Code' : ['93', '92', '91', '90'],
     'Area Code' : ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7', '31,32,43,44,54,56,7, ', '434,34,4', '00, 89']}
```

I want a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'Date' : ['2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01'],
     'Combined Code' : ['931,932,933,934,935,936,937', '9231,9232,9243,9244,9254,9256,927,92 ,', '91434,9134,914', '9000, 9089']}
```

What I have tried is:

```
list(chain(*(product(*(s.split(",") for s in e)) for e in zip(*d.values()))))
```

But unable to Manage this all in a dictionary.

Comment: What *exactly* is the output you want? You want a dictionary but what you've tried will produce a list.

Comment: @ msvalkon-- What I need is a dictionary, but I can do it on lists only that is why I said "But unable to Manage this all in a dictionary." :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a little *brute force*, but hey... it's late.

```
d = {'Date': ['2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01'], 'Country Code': ['93', '92', '91', '90'], 'Area Code': ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7', '31,32,43,44,54,56,7, ', '434,34,4', '00, 89']}

new = {'Date': d['Date'], 'Combined Code': []}

for i, code in enumerate(d['Country Code']):
    area = map(str.strip, d['Area Code'][i].split(','))
    new['Combined Code'].append(",".join(["".join(item) for item in zip([code] * len(area), area)]))

print new
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'Date': ['2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01'], 'Combined Code': ['931,932,933,934,935,936,937', '9231,9232,9243,9244,9254,9256,927,92', '91434,9134,914', '9000,9089']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with this. The differences in the desired output is due to spaces in the input.

```
d = {'Date' : ['2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01', '2013-05-01'],
     'Country Code' : ['93', '92', '91', '90'],
     'Area Code' : ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7', '31,32,43,44,54,56,7, ', '434,34,4', '00, 89']};

merged = [];

# assumes that the length of "Country Code" is always the same as "Area Code"
for index in range(0, len(d["Area Code"])):
    merged.append(",".join(map(lambda x: d["Country Code"][index] + x.strip(), d["Area Code"][index].split(","))));

# add the result to the dictionary and remove the old entries
d["Combined Code"] = merged;
del d["Country Code"];
del d["Area Code"];

print d;
```

Comment: Minor nit-pick, but you probably want to account for stripping the space on the '00, 89'.